# My OOP is not working with my menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, menu, hamburger-menu

I tried to make the menu in OOP Javascript to prevent repeatable code. I have two menu element "toggleBtn" for Desktop Burger Icon and "toggleBtnMobile" for Mobile Bruger Icon.

The problem right now: It is not working.

```
 var $this = $(this),
      $navSidebar = $('#navSidebar'),
      $navDlrz = $('#navDlrz'),
      $toggleBtn = $('#toggleBtn'),
      $toggleBtnMobile = $('#toggleBtnMobile'),
      $menuHasChildren = $('.menu-item-has-children'),
      $subMenu = $menuHasChildren.find('ul.sub-menu');

  // Menu class
  function Menu(menu) {

            this.menu = menu;
            var one = menu.children().eq(1); // Burger Icons top bar
            var two = menu.children().eq(2); // Burger Icons middle bar
            var three = menu.children().eq(3); // Burger Icons bottom bar

       }


// When the Nav is clicked, the burger Icon transforms into "X"
   Menu.prototype.openNav = function() {

        one.addClass('One');
        two.addClass('Two');
        three.addClass('Three');
        $navSidebar.css('left', '0px');
        $navDlrz.css('left', '200px');

   };



 // Back to standard Icon
   Menu.prototype.closeNav = function() {

        one.removeClass('One');
        two.removeClass('Two');
        three.removeClass('Three');
        $navSidebar.css('left', '-200px');
        $navDlrz.css('left', '0px');

   }

Menu.prototype.toggleNav = function() { 

        menu.click(function() {

            var $this = $(this),
                $className = $this.attr('class');

            switch($className) {
                case 'navbar-toggle':
                    $this.addClass('open');
                    this.openNav();
                    break;
                case 'navbar-toggle open':
                    $this.removeClass('open');
                    $menuHasChildren.removeClass('open');
                    $menuHasChildren.find('ul.sub-menu').removeClass('open');
                    this.closeNav();
                    break;
            }

        });

   }
```

> Important notice: I don't need any framework regarding menu toggeling. I'm learning at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is closure

```
function Menu(menu) {

            this.menu = menu;
            var one = menu.children().eq(1); // Burger Icons top bar
            var two = menu.children().eq(2); // Burger Icons middle bar
            var three = menu.children().eq(3); // Burger Icons bottom bar

       }
```

here you declared one, two and three variables with var key. these variables can be seen only in Menu constructor, declare them with 'this' keyword, and use them with 'this'

Comment: It didn't help. It says the this.openNav() or this.closeNav() is not a function.

Comment: you declared your variables in Menu constructor and used them as a object key in Menu.prototype.openNav method. for example:
"function Menu() {
var one = menu.children().eq(1); // must be: this.one = menu.children().eq(1);
}
Menu.prototype.openNav = function () {
one.removeClass('One'); 
}"

you can not declare variable with 'var' and use it out of constructor

Comment: It didn't help as I said before...I used them with this keyword but here's the output in the console: 

VM2348:58 Uncaught TypeError: this.closeNav is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:58:26)

and

VM2348:58 Uncaught TypeError: this.openNav is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:58:26)